# Loading namespaced classes with Symfony 1.4's autoloader?

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony-1.4, autoload

How to register namespaces (with PHP 5.3) in the Symfony 1.4 for the autoloader class feature (like the [Symfony 2.0](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html))?

Comment: Were you able to get Symfony 1.4 autoloading working with namespaces finally?  If so, can you let me know how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Autoloader from Symfony2 in Symfony 1.4 framework.

**1. Copy Symfony2 classloaders to vendor directory of your Symfony 1.4 sandbox project:**

> SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/Symfony2/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php
>
> SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/Symfony2/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcUniversalClassLoader.php

**2. Modify your SF_ROOT_DIR/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php file as follows:**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/autoload/sfClassLoader.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration {

    public function setup() {
        $this->namespacesClassLoader();
        $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
    }

    public function namespacesClassLoader() {
       if (extension_loaded('apc')) {
           $loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('S2A');
       } else {
           $loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
       }
       $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
          'Pohon' => __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/Pohon/src'));
       $loader->register();
    }

}
```

**3. Register desired namespaces:** 

eg. I want to load class:

> Pohon\Tools\String\Utils\Slugify.

Filename must be:

> SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/Pohon/src/Pohon/Tools/String/Utils/Slugify.php

and registered namespace as follows:

> Pohon => SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/Pohon/src

Comment: The Autoloader project can be found here: https://github.com/Symfony-Plugins/sfClassLoaderPlugin.

Comment: Breautiful, thanks! I had to add `use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;  
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcUniversalClassLoader;` after the imports in the ProjectConfiguraration.class.php file. Also, here's the link for the ClassLoader bundle (before these classes got deprecated): https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/tree/2.6

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and it's very easy. Just install it on your machine (you probably have already since it's 2015 now) and run in your project folder:

```
composer init
```

You can then install all the packages you want with composer and include just this line in your `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Note that paths may differ if you changed the default Symfony1.4 directory structure.

Comment: Symfony 1.4 don't know how to load  classes within a namespace, you must implement this feature. Composer is just a package/lib manager.

Comment: Composer does provide a ClassLoader as well and when you install (to use Composer slang "require") packages with it all you have to do is then include the `vendor/autoload.php` script above. Composer takes care of mapping the namespaces in the installed packages, all of them. Have you tried it? I do that and it works quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you for this solution it worked for me. you need to specify vendor-dir: "lib/vendor" to have libraries in the original vendor dir of sf 1.4; used that for amp-library and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony uses the `spl_autoload_register()` function to register its own autoloader (`sfAutoload`).

You can register your own handler in the `initialize()` function of your Project/Application/Plugin. (whichever applies).

This is, for example, also what the `Swift_Mailer` plugin does: it registers its own autoloader when needed.