# Duplicate class names in different paths in Symfony 1.4 causing problems

Tags: php, classpath, symfony-1.4

I've inherited a Symfony 1.4 application to manage.  I'm running into a problem where I've created new classes and unknown to me, I've duplicated some existing class names (in other paths).

Apart from renaming my classes, is there anyway to specify a classpath of sorts to the class I want to use?  In Java we can easily append the entire class path, but I'm not quite sure if/how this can be done in PHP5 and/or Symfony 1.4.

Is this even possible, or is my only choice to ensure I have no class name conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another [SO thread response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519132/827480) where @Jan Míšek proposes a solution.  Unfortunately it isn't marked as the accepted response, but it gives fairly good instructions how to migrate the Symfony2 autoloader which supports namespaces to Symfony 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces is your solution. Check out http://www.php.net/namespaces.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried using namespaces, but either I'm doing something wrong, or the Symfony 1.4 autoloader is creating an issue as the class is not found when specifying the namespace.  I haven't spent the time debugging it, but I suspect that the autoloader doesn't recognize namespaces and just loads one of the two classes based on class names.  Have you successfully used namespaces with Symfony 1.4?

Comment: @EricB. Which version of PHP do you run?

Comment: @j0k - PHP 5.4.9.  Have also tried on 5.3.x with same result.

Comment: @EricB. You're right, I don't think the native sf1.4 autoloader care about namespace ..